# Use Action filter to return json and then redirect to action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created normal asp mvc controller named ApiController to return `json` results. In one of  its action method I want to return json and then redirect to another action method.

After returning json to the api request I have to post notification using `SignalR`

I tried using `Action filter` but it is not redirecting to other action method.

**Action Method 1**

```
 [NotifyUserActionFilter]
 public ActionResult NotifyUser(int ID)
 {       
    return Json("true",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

**Action Method 2**

```
   //the returning view has signalR javascript in it
   public ActionResult ThankYou()
   {
        string Tempval = TempData["tempID"].ToString(); 
        return View();
   }
```

**Action Filter**

```
public class NotifyUserActionFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        var ID = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["ID"];

        filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("tempID", ID);

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary 
                    { 
                        { "controller", "Api" }, 
                        { "action", "Thankyou" } 
                    });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need the result from "NotifyUser" and you consume it on your view i would approach your issue using a jquery AJAX call.

Simply, Call your "NotifyUser" method in Ajax. In the "success" of the ajax call i would test to see if the json result is "true". if it is i would then redirect to the new view. setting "window.location....."

If you dont use the json result, then you can just redirect in the "NotifyUser" method.

Comment: "NotifyUser" will be consumed by mobile app. Actually I want to return json result when "NotifyUser" will be called and then redirect to view "ThankYou" where I am running the signalR script

Comment: You need to do the redirect in your client (mobile) app. Where you consume the result of NotifyUser you then redirect to the new view "Thankyou".